# Relationship with between Clifford multiplication and pullback

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, spin-geometry, index-theory, clifford-algebras

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field on the even-dimensional sphere $S^n$. Let $S(TS^n)=S^+(TS^n)\oplus S^-(TS^n)$ be the spinor bundle over $S^n$ equipped with a bundle metric that is compatible with the Clifford multiplication, which is trivial for all $n$ if the choose the trivial spin structure in the situation $n=1$. Let $v=c(X):S^+(TS^n)\to S^-(TS^n)$ be the Clifford multiplication of $X$ and $v^*:S^-(TS^n)\to S^+(TS^n)$ be the adjoint of $v$ with respect to Hermitian metrics on $S^\pm (TS^n)$. Let

$$V=v+v^*:S(TS^n)\to S(TS^n)$$

and let $f: X\to S^n$ be a smooth map.

**My question is how to prove that:(1)
$$f^*(V^2)=(f^*V)^2:S(TX)\to S(TX)$$**

**(2) Why can $f^*V$ extend to action on $S(TX)\otimes E$ such that for any $\alpha\in S(TX),u\in E$, we have $(f^*V)(\alpha\otimes u)=(-1)^{deg(\alpha)}\alpha\otimes (f^*V)(u)$?**

Here $E$ is a Hermitian vector bundle on $X$.

I guess that it needs some properties about Clifford multiplication,  but I have no idea to prove the identity.

Could you give me some help with the details? Thanks!